# How to create a user and assign a password in mysql

Tags: mysql

What is going on with the below?  Why will mysql not let me in? I am using 5.6

```
root@ip-10-93-145-98:/home/ubuntu# echo "grant all privileges on *.* to 'really'@'%' identified by 'stupid';" | mysql -u root -ptest101
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
root@ip-10-93-145-98:/home/ubuntu# mysql -u really -pstupid
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'really'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Comment: Tried `mysql --user=really --password=stupid`?

Comment: add space after -p .mysql -u really -p stupid

Comment: Use this instead `mysql -ureally -p` the mysql processor will then challenge you for the password and as you enter it only show one `*` per character of the password. Hence people cannot look over your shoulder and see your password

Answer (score 0):

Run a `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` after the `GRANT ..`.
Try to login again after that.